# Database schema for leave report with changing structure

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a requirement to show leave history and forecast. The data is received weekly in a report which I need to store in a table. I can use any DB supported by Java.

A sample of the data looks like this:

[image]

To be able to show past totals by department I need to store the data that comes out in the report each week.

How to store the forecast data, as the data structure of the report keeps changing. In the sample above the last 12 columns are the 12 months following the date the report was run. Next month the first column will be October etc.

I have create a fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qYHCeUoaZkm5eu1y2BoBwo/10)

I have considered just storing the last 4 weeks of reports (each report in a separate table) and inserting work group totals into a separate totals table where each row would represent a department and its totals.

If there is a better way - what sort of data structure/schema should I use?

Comment: I don't understand why a weekly report contains 12 months of data

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 approaches:

1. You can add a `date` and `forecast` column and then get rid of the columns that are named after month/years. It's like `transpose` action in Excel. Additionally, since `Dept`, `Leave_Balance`, `projected_balance_6m` will not be in the same grain as the new columns, I'd create a new table. Example rows from the new table would be like:

   ```
   +------------+-----------+----------+
   | EmployeeID | YearMonth | Forecast |
   +------------+-----------+----------+
   |        456 |    201901 |        0 |
   |        456 |    201902 |        5 |
   +------------+-----------+----------+
   ```
2. Again in a new table, you can add a `year` column and make the forecast column names to resemble months. This wouldn't be continuous as your current solution but easier to handle in the BI software.

   ```
   +------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   | EmployeeID | Year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun |
   +------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |        456 | 2019 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
   |        456 | 2020 |   0 |   5 |   0 |   6 |   0 |   0 |
   |        123 | 2020 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
   +------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   ```
3. Other approach could be to rename columns relative to current date. Here, `cur` is `SEPT19`, `cur+1` is `OCT19` and so on. This solution will have the least impact but, drawback of this approach is, it is not clear when you last updated the table, and what `cur` value is actually. So, that information should be made available somewhere.

   ```
   +-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-------+-------+
   | ID  | Name | Dept  | Leave_Balance | p_balance_6m | cur | cur+1 | cur+2 |
   +-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-------+-------+
   | 456 | Mary | Sales | 32.3          | 45.6         |   0 |    0  |     0 |
   +-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-------+-------+
   ```

I like the first and second solutions more because they are more self contained. Your choice would depend on how much you want to rely on BI software (Tableau, Qlikview etc).